# Need to change my key header from colour to stats using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help changing the key title for this ggplot, let me know (new to R)

```
combined_hist_data <- ggplot(data = SL_dataframe, aes(SL_dataframe$combined_SL_Data)) +
geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="peachpuff", bins = 30) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 3.98253, colour = "mean_C"), linetype="solid", size=0.7, show.legend=TRUE) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 4.474164, colour= "mean_E"), linetype="solid", size=0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 4.432707, colour= "CI_SL_E_lower"), linetype="dashed", size=0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 4.513602, colour= "CI_SL_E_upper"), linetype="dashed", size=0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 3.939077, colour= "CI_SL_C_lower"), linetype="dashed", size=0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 4.025749, colour= "CI_SL_C_upper"), linetype="dashed", size=0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
labs(x=expression(bold("mean_dist_SL")), y=expression(bold("Frequency")), title=expression(bold("distribution of SL_combined")))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH1Z9.jpg)

Comment: So what's the problem? You can set/change the title in `labs(title = "...")`

Comment: Not the title of the figure, my key with all the line headers (i.e., "mean_C...")..It says colors and I want to change that to stats...I'm aware of using colours will automatically use that as the header, but I want my legend title to change

Comment: To change the legend title you can use `guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "..."))`.

Comment: `labs(colour = "Stats", <other labs>)` should do it if I'm understanding the issue correctly.

Comment: Thank you, guides(colour = ...) worked perfectly. Turned out great. Cheers!